# Brokered Component not working when deploying to client

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-component

I created a test App with brokered copmonent and it runs smooth on my machine, but when moved it to a tablet and did all the required settings (regsvr32, icacls), it throws an exception. then I went and downloaded the Microsoft Northwind sample and it act the same. works fine on my machine but not on the other tablet. Am I missing any thing here? here is the exception, it's casting exception and Access denied exception:
 Unable to cast COM object of type 'NorthwindRT.DAL.FileWatcher' to interface type 'NorthwindRT.DAL.IFileWatcherClass'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{23F40340-AEB1-5774-5705-64488C9BDD3A}' failed due to the following error: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
but I did on the tablet the same things I did on the developing machine!
I moved the required files to the correct directory and enabled read/execute to all applications and I registered the proxy using regsvr32. Also the user can access the directory where the implementation dll is located so Access is denied exception is weird.
I did my research about brokered comp and I am doing exactly like the available documentations!
Any Ideas? Am I missing anything here? Is there extra settings I need to do? is my system missing any required dlls?

Comment: Finally could you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The App does not have access to msvcr120d.dll
add "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" to this dll and it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on brokered component, so far I did had some success in development as well as deployment.

**Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))**

You need to run icacls in the folder where you have the proxystub.dll and the winmd implementation.

> icacls . /T /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":RX

Now if you're deploying to a device that does not have a dev environment (i.e. Visual studio), you need to install **Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015** (you can use whatever VS version you have, it just happend that i am using VS2015). You can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145). And one more thing, since you don't have a development environment in the device, you would like to deploy **Release** assemblies **not Debug** so that the assemblies won't be referencing libraries or dll that is for debug (i.e. msvcr120.dll instead of msvcr120**d**.dll) because it won't be found in a clean device.

Lastly, I have a [blog](https://xamltips.wordpress.com/2015/11/13/brokered-component-for-uwp-on-windows-10/) about brokered component. You might want to check it out.